# A list of publications by Issai Schur, and Ferdinand Frobenius

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm interested in works of Frobenius and Schur and I am wondering if there is a list of their publications somewhere that I can go through. I have found some of their works [here](http://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/JFM.html) But it seems like everything is in German. Are there any English translations of their works? If not I better start learning some German.

Comment: Start to learn German, nothing compares to study in the native language of the author, besides that German is a really beautiful language.

Comment: @user42912, Yeah, I think that would be the only way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find many but here are a few:

**Frobenius**

I'm assuming you came across "Theory of hypercomplex quantities":
http://neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/0/6/5/3065888/frobenius_-_hypercomplex_i.pdf

"New Proof of Sylow's Theorem":
http://people.cam.cornell.edu/~gfriend/resources/frobenius/gutfraind_Frobenius1887.pdf

**Schur**

"Issai Schur's posthumous notes on elementary number theory":
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09629410408000021?journalCode=tbsh20
(Requires subscription/money)

"Matrices that commute with their derivative. On a letter from Schur to Wielandt":
http://www.math.wisc.edu/~hans/paper_archive/other_papers/hs163.pdf
or
http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/preprints/files/HolMS12_ppt.pdf

Also, the book "Pioneers of Representation Theory: Frobenius, Burnside, Schur, and Brauer (History of Mathematics)" by Charles W. Curtis offers analysis of their (translated) published work.

Comment: I've read the article by Holtz et. al. and just borrowed the book Pioneers of Representation theory to read. At first glance it seems like it's mostly gonna be on the aspects of the representation theory related to classification of finite simple groups. Thanks for the suggestions and the links.